# Si "trilogía" son tres películas, ¿cuál es el término para nueve?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

A estas alturas todos estamos familiarizados ya con la palabra "trilogía" para definir una serie de tres películas. De hecho la definición va un poco más allá:

> **[trilogía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=af93q0t)**
>
> Del gr. *τριλογία trilogía*.
>
> 1. f. Conjunto de tres obras literarias o musicales que tienen entre sí enlace histórico o unidad de protagonismo o intención.
> 2. f. Conjunto de tres obras trágicas de un mismo autor, presentadas a concurso en los festivales teatrales de la Grecia clásica.

Sin embargo, ahora vamos a tener la saga de Star Wars con un total de 9 películas principales (más los *spin-offs*). Se podría decir que es una trilogía de trilogías, pero ¿cuál sería el término apropiado para definir a la saga de nueve películas? ¿[Enea](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FFWcFOr)logía? ¿[Nona](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QavkIIy)logía? ¿Algún otro?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yo diría que valen las dos, depende si usas los prefijo derivados del latín (*uni-, bi-, tri-, cuatri-,...*) o del griego (*mono-, di-, tri-, tetra-,...*).

Lo más normal es usar el término cuando son series de tres (trilogía) tanto para películas como libros y para ese caso el prefijo es siempre *tri-*, ya sea en latín o en griego.

Para Fundéu también son válidas las dos formas. De su entrada [*nonalogía/enealogía*](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/nonalogia-enealogia/):

> Son formaciones perfectamente válidas que simplemente continúan la
>   serie *trilogía, cuatrilogía/tetralogía*, etc. La forma *nonalogía* se
>   basa en el latín, mientras que la forma *enealogía* se basa en el griego
>   (de modo similar a *nonágono* y *eneágono*, ambas correctas para el
>   polígono de nueve lados). Que no esté en el diccionario de la RAE no
>   significa que [no se puedan usar ni que sean incorrectas](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Diccionario_de_la_lengua_espa%C3%B1ola#T.C3.A9rminos_incluidos).

Answer (score 5):

**Enealogía** de acuerdo a este [articulo de Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serie_cinematogr%C3%A1fica)

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serie_cinematogr%C3%A1fica

Comment: No está mal, una saga de 89 películas, eso es al menos dos al año desde que se inició...

Comment: Por favor, añadid las partes relevantes del artículo enlazado al post. No creo que wikipedia vaya a desaparecer, pero es mejor tener aquí el cnenido relevante sin tener que ir a otro sitio y leer/estudiar todo el artículo enlazado.